# How can I use an event to access a form's control?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, events

I am looking for an example of how a class can call back to a parent form's control using an event. In this case, the event will occur in the class, not the parent. For example if you have a class and something happens in the class that will require a form's textbox to be updated.

I have done this by exposing a form's textbox as a property then passing an instance of the form to the class but this seems like a lot of work just to update a textbox.

I am trying to self teach C# so Im a newbie.
Ken

Comment: How are you triggering the event? Is it in response to a user action? A timer? At random? You probably don't need an event.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    EventClass eventClassInstance;

    public Form()
    {
        eventClassInstance = new EventClass();
        eventClassInstance.actualEvent += new EventClass.CustomEventHandler(eventHandler);
    }

    private void eventHandler(object sender)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

public class EventClass
{
    public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender);
    public CustomEventHandler actualEvent;// This gets fired somewhere

    public EventClass()
    {

    }
}
```

This is a simple example of an event handler in the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w369ty8x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on publishing events.  Depending on the information that you are wanting to pass you may need to create a Custom EventArgs to pass the information, then create your delegate and event.

Here is a quick and dirty example borrowing heavily on the above MSDN Link, the Timer was added for a quick test:

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Class1 myClass = new Class1();
        myClass.RaiseCustomEvent += new EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>(myClass_RaiseCustomEvent);

    }

    void myClass_RaiseCustomEvent(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = e.Message;
    }

}
```

**Class1**

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Class1
    { 
        public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> RaiseCustomEvent;
        public Class1()
        {
            Timer tmr = new Timer();
            tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
            tmr.Interval = 2000;
            tmr.Start();
        }

        void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CustomEventArgs ea = new CustomEventArgs("Hello World");
            RaiseCustomEvent(this, ea);
        }

    }

    public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public CustomEventArgs(string s)
        {
            msg = s;
        }
        private string msg;
        public string Message
        {
            get { return msg; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `EventHandler<CustomEventArgs>`?

Comment: @BenVoigt You are right, it would be a lot cleaner. I changed it thanks.

Comment: The cast can now go away also.

Comment: I have to take some time to look at all the examples to see how they will apply. My initial request may have been incomplete. To clarify: The code would have a form which would have a "status" textbox. Other classes can update the status box

Comment: @kenmtb as long as the Event Signatures are the same you can assign a Common Event handler to each of the Events that you want to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this process:

1. Expose an event in the data class
2. When the textbox needs updating, fire the event
3. Listen for the event in the parent form
4. In the event handler, update the textbox

Comment: Im still new, what would a data class be?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your class would trigger its update action. So lets consider a simple case, where user would click a button to invoke the class to do something. You can pass the callback from the form to the class as following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        class1.DoSomething(OnSuccess, OnError);
    }

    private void OnSuccess(string newValue)
    {
        textBox1.Text = newValue;
    }

    private void OnError(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

The class would finish its task and pass the updated value to the callback, with no knowledge about how the caller would do to the updated value:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void DoSomething(Action<string> onSuccess, Action<Exception> onError)
    {
        try
        {
            // Logic to really do something...

            if (onSuccess != null)
                onSuccess("updated value");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (onError != null)
                onError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you have learnt lambda expression, you can pass the call back to your class on the fly:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1 class1 = new Class1();
    class1.DoSomething(
        newValue => textBox1.Text = newValue,
        ex => MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error));
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. I have a LOT to learn regarding C#. It looks like you are using a function that belongs to a parent in the child class. Is it OK to call back to the parent? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I can't quite catch your question. `you are using a function that belongs to a parent in the child class` Yes, and this is a call back to the "parent".